# How to pass multiple variable from php to python script

Tags: php, python, command-line-interface

I need help on this x-x

assuming my php has 3 variables

```
<?php
$var1 = "1";
$var2 = "2";
$var3 = "3";
?>
```

So on the "exec" part im a bit stuck and confused, how do i pass those 3 variable into my python script, and how do i receive those 3 variables in my python script?

Comment: my python script will be script to insert data into sqlite, but for this you can just assume the python script is to print out the variables received. I will edit it later :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just pass them as command line arguments:

```
exec ( "/path/to/python/script.py $var1 $var2 $var3" );
```

Then in your Python script you can read them like this:

```
import sys

print sys.argv[1] # first parameter
print sys.argv[2] # second parameter
print sys.argv[3] # third parameter
```

Btw: `sys.argv[0]` contains the name of your script, that is why you start with index `1`.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: If my python script is in the same dir of the php script can i run it like `exec ( "script.py $var1 $var2 $var3" );` ?

Comment: Probably. Why don't you just try it yourself :) ?

Comment: Hello. is that work? I can't execute python script on server using php variable