# How to pass variable from php to python

Tags: php, python

My php code:

```
$param1 = 1;
$param2 = 5;
$pyscript = "C:\\users\\server\\test\\integration2.py";
$python = 'C:\\Python34\\python.exe';

$cmd = "$python $pyscript";
exec("$cmd $param1 $param2", $output1);
var_dump($output1);
```

My python code

```
import sys    
a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]  
print(a)
print(b)
```

But i get

```
array(0) { }
```

What is wrong here..Please help me..

Without parameter the code works..

Answer (score 0):

> follow the link given below:

[php to python example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197815/how-to-pass-variable-from-php-to-python)

[php to python example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758299/how-to-pass-multiple-variable-from-php-to-python-script)