# Manually Connecting to wifi by keying in ssid and password on RPi web page server

Tags: php, python, linux, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to connect to a specific wifi network by keying in the ssid and password manually and then submitting using a button. This is all done on a RPi web page server which I am accessing through an access point of the RPi. What I am trying to achieve is that php gets the values(ssid and password) of the network, and pass it on to python so that it can connect. I have tried the following codes but to no avail. Would appreciate any help.
HTML page:

```
<form action="wificonn.php" method="POST"> 
    SSID:<input type="text" name="ssid"/> 
    Password:<input type="password" name=password"/> 
    input type ="submit" /> </form>
```

PHP code(wificonn.php):

```
<?php
$var1 = "ssid";
$var2 = "password";
exec ( "/usr/bin/python wigi.py $var1 $var2 $var3" );
?>
```

Referenced the php code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758299/how-to-pass-multiple-variable-from-php-to-python-script)

Python wifi connection referenced from [here](https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scanning.html)

Comment: Does the `wigi.py` be executed?

Comment: Yep, it is supposed to be executed from wificonn.php @stovfl